# Primitive roots modulo $n$ and $2n$.

Tags: group-theory

How do we prove that, for any given odd number $n$, there exists primitive root modulo $n$ if and only if there exist primitive roots modulo $2n$?

As I have read only group theory till now, so please try not to introduce the concept of rings and fields.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $n$ be an odd number. If $x$ is odd then for any integer $k$, $x^k\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, and, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem,
$x^k\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ iff $x^k\equiv 1 \pmod{2n}$. Recall that $\varphi(n)=\varphi(2n)$.